# Get last row name by column, then DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I need to get the last username registered in my members table. The last registered has the highest ID number.

At the moment, I can get the highest ID with this code, but I need to get the lowest.

$resultlatestuser = mysql_query("SELECT * from $tbl_name ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 0,1;");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($resultlatestuser);
echo $row[1];

This echos the ID as john, but john has the *lowest* ID: 1.

This is what my database looks like, for example I need Dayancbro echo'd because he has the highest ID.

http://puu.sh/2k4Hh

- James

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY 'id' ASC` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to use aggregate functions:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM $tablename
```